# Angular: issue with two-field data binding

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this radio button in my ionic app:

```
<ion-radio ng-model="data.sort" ng-value="['-timestamp','model']" ng-click="closeSortPopover();">Recent model (default)</ion-radio>
```

but it doesn't check itself when I set `$scope.data.sort` to `['-timestamp','model']` somewhere else in the controller or view.

See the [codePen](http://codepen.io/LouisDoe/pen/VvowGJ) here.

Comment: you mean doesnt check itself???

Comment: oh yes ! sorry, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i wrap your array to a scope variable it works just fine

**html**

```
<ion-nav-view>
     <ion-view>
       <ion-content>

          <ion-radio ng-model="data.sort" ng-value="someValue" ng-click="closeSortPopover();">['-timestamp','model']</ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="data.sort" ng-value="'brand'"   ng-click="closeSortPopover()">Brand</ion-radio>

         <br/><br/>

         <button id="resetbutton" class="button icon-left ion-ios-reload button-dark" ng-click='data.sort=someValue;'>Set to data.sort to ['-timestamp','model']</button>

         <br/><br/>

         data.sort = {{data.sort}}
       </ion-content>
     </ion-view>  
</ion-nav-view>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTitle = 'This header hides the content below';
  $scope.someValue = ["-timestamp","model"];
  $scope.data={};
  $scope.data.sort = $scope.someValue;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mat. perfect !